# Applying a value to a new XML element with attributes using PHP's simpleXML

Tags: php, simplexml, addchild

Here is a function (in a class that deals with comments) that creates a comment element

```
function add($id,$message){
    $newcomment = $this->source->addChild('comment');
    $newcomment->addAttribute('user',$id);
    $newcomment->addAttribute('timestamp',time());

    $newcomment = $message; // <--------- fail

    $this->source->asXML($this->save);
    return(true);
}
```

All of this works but I obviously don't know what I'm doing with the line I'm pointing at. But I basically want to put the message in the comment element like so:

```
<comments>
  <comment id="12345678" timestamp="1355812061">
    Hey friend, what's up?
  </comment>
  <comment id="87654321" timestamp="1355813155">
    Nothing much, just have this problem with simpleXML
  </comment>
</comments>
```

But what I have works except that the message isn't set.

So my question is, is this possible and if so, what must I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the value of the newly created child element with the 2nd parameter to [`addChild()`](http://php.net/simplexmlelement), like this:

```
$newcomment = $this->source->addChild('comment', $message);
```

Then you can get rid of the line you're pointing to.

Comment: I am thoroughly embarrassed, sir. I guess I wasn't thinking. However I still have the dilemma about modifying the value later on.

Comment: @Wendrom - How do you need to modify the value later on? Can you show the code that is doing that? It might be easier to just remove this current element, and replace it with a new element if you need to update its value.

Comment: That would certainly be easier but I am lazy about reordering the elements by their timestamp value because surely if I re-add the element it will end up on the bottom and not it's original position. But if it comes down to it, I'll reorder it.

Comment: @Wendrom - Actually if you use PHP's DOMDocument instead of SimpleXML, you can replace children in-place.

Answer (score 1):

> So my question is, is this possible and if so, what must I do?

Yes, this is possible. You can write to the element directly using the array-style sytax:

```
$newcomment[0] = $message;
```

---

SimpleXML does not allow writing text content to a plain variable, but it does allow writing to an element with array-style access (`$node[$n] = 'string'`) or property-style access (`$node->child = 'string'`).

To write to the element contained in the variable, use index `0` with the array syntax as shown above.

Answer (score 0):

Just add a second parameter to `addChild()` when creating the comment field:

```
$newcomment = $this->source->addChild('comment', $message);
```